# How to one click deploy rails app on digital ocean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, deployment, digital-ocean

I have created a droplet on digital ocean of ruby on rails with already configured nginx and unicorn server.

How can i deploy my already created rails app to that server.

Should I use capistrano to deploy? Or is there any other way to deploy?

I have been to digital ocean guide for deployment but it is very confusing for a beginner like me.

[Tutorial used for creating droplet.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image)

I have the same droplet created

Comment: The one-click install does not use Capistrano, nor Unicorn. It's a very basic Rails install using Webbrick as the server. If you can get your app running within their very simple  config, that's a good step one, then add complications once you confirmed your app launches in Webbrick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will try to explain it step by step.
Use Ubuntu 12 or 14.
You need Nginx, RoR, Capistrano, git, passenger.

**0. Log int to server**

```
ssh root@server_ip
```

You can find ip here https://cloud.digitalocean.com/droplets

**1. Create a user (if needed)**

```
adduser deployer
```

**2. Move user to sudo users**

```
visudo
deployer ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

**3. Install bash for him**

```
nano /etc/passwd
Change /bin/sh to /bin/bash
```

**4. Change ssh-port for security**

```
nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
Change Port 22 on Port XXXX (where XXXX is any number)
```

**5. reload ssh**

**6. Enter by ssh with our new user**

```
ssh -p XXXX deployer@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

**7. Update system if needed**

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install curl
```

**8. Install rvm:**

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
rvm requirements
```

**9. Install ruby, postgres, etc..**

```
rvm install [version of ruby similar to app]

sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

If cluster was not created, do it manually:

```
sudo pg_createcluster [postgresql_version] main --start

sudo apt-get install language-pack-en-base
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Create postgres user

```
sudo -u postgres psql 
alter user postgres with password '[password]';
```

## To quit from psql press \q

```
sudo apt-get install git-core
```

**10. Install gem passenger:**

```
gem install passenger
```

**11. Install nginx using passenger**

```
rvmsudo passenger-install-nginx-module
```

**12. Set swap if needed**

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swap bs=1M count=1024
sudo mkswap /swap
sudo swapon /swap
```

**13. Change config of nginx (server section):**

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name www.yourhost.com;
      root /somewhere/public;   # <--- be sure to point to 'public'!
      passenger_enabled on;
      location ^~ /assets/ 
           { gzip_static on; 
           expires max; 
           add_header Cache-Control public; 
      }
 }
```

**14. Clone good script for nginx start/stop/restart if Ubuntu:**

```
git clone https://github.com/vkurennov/rails-nginx-passenger-ubuntu.git
sudo cp nginx/nginx.conf /etc/init.d/nginx.conf
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx/conf
```

**15. Run nginx:**

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

**BOYA!! Check your browser!**

**Let's go to our app!**

**1. gem ‘capistrano’ for depoly**

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'rvm-capistrano'
  gem 'net-ssh’, ‘2.7.0'
end
```

**2. Run:**

```
capify .
```

**Open deploy.rb and set:**

```
set :application, 'app_title'
set :repository,  'app_repo'
```

**5. add:**

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require "rvm/capistrano"

load 'deploy/assets’

set :port, XXXX
set :use_sudo, false

set :rails_env, :production
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "/home/deployer/app_title"
set :user, 'deployer'

role :web, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"                          # Your HTTP server, Apache/etc
role :app, "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"                          # This may be the same as your `Web` server
role :db,  "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX", :primary => true # This is where Rails migrations will run
```

**6. cap deploy:check**

**7. cap deploy:setup**

```
set :bundle_cmd, "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451@global/bin/bundle"
set :bundle_dir, "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p451"

set :rvm_type, :user
set :rvm_ruby_string, 'ruby-2.0.0-p451@global'
```

**8. Recipes for deploy:**

```
namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end
```

**9. Clone ssh-key on server and add to repo**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

**10. Add gem ‘therubyracer’**

**11. cap deploy:cold**

Boya! I opened for questions if smth is not clear.

Comment: I know about this process and have done for one of my project successfully.
but currently I have droplet created with auto installed rails.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use Capistrano for deployment, it is best practice to use Capistrano you can refer http://robmclarty.com/blog/how-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-with-git-and-capistrano.

let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image 

I have this image and want to use this only.
Can you guide me?

Comment: Means you need to configure application with nginx and Unicorn?

Comment: Yes I need to deploy and configure my application with currently installed nginx and unicorn

Comment: you can refer 
http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-ruby-deploy-capistrano-host-nginx-unicorn/
https://coderwall.com/p/yz8cha/deploying-rails-app-using-nginx-unicorn-postgres-and-capistrano-to-digital-ocean

Comment: Thanks but currently of no use.
can you please explain [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-1-click-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-14-04-image) this

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also use *mina* for deployment. It is like capistrano but it is easier and much more faster than capistrano.

Take a look at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-mina-to-deploy-a-ruby-on-rails-application

Comment: I want to deploy my app and configure it with currently installed nginx and unicorn.